# NameError in Python interpreter

Tags: python

Here is my init:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(".."))

from myModule import *
```

Then in command line, same directory:

```
Python 2.7.4 (default, Sep 26 2013, 03:20:26) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> c = myClass
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'myClass' is not defined
```

Comment: Why are you expecting `__init__.py` to have run at this point? *Which* `__init__.py`? How would Python know that you wanted it to run?

Comment: Could you show us your directory structure? And you import in __init__ file not in u python.

Comment: In other words: Your `__init__.py` is completely irrelevant to your error.

Answer (score 2):

```
Python 2.7.4 (default, Sep 26 2013, 03:20:26) 
[GCC 4.7.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> c = myClass
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'myClass' is not defined
```

You haven't imported myClass, so your Python interpreter does not know what "myClass" means.

To make it understand that, type something like:

```
from themodule.wheremyclassisdefined import myClass
```

And it will work.

This has nothing to do with `__init__.py` at all.

Comment: I thought "from module import *" imports all the classes (myClass is inside module.py).  I put that inside __init__.py, so shouldn't it import everytime I launch the command line?

Comment: In your computer, you can have a hundred different `__init__.py`. By naming it so, when you import the folder name, you import that file.

Comment: See my answer on how to do it right.

Comment: @onepiece: No, the __init__.py is not automatically launched at all. There are ways to automatically launch thing sin Python, but that's not what you want to do. You have to step back and ask a question explaining what you are trying to achieve, because whatever it is you are trying to do, you are attempting to solve it the wrong way.

Comment: I am trying to import module "myModule" automatically so I don't have to manually import it when I launch the command line.  Can you help me understand what the init.py is actually for then?

Comment: @onepiece: The `__init__.py` is used to make a directory into a module. To run things automatically on command-line startup you use the PYTHONSTARTUP environment variable: http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP  You should have asked how to do that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to import it first to your python interpreter.

For example if this is your directory structure:

```
|package
    |module
        __init__.py
        someothermodule.py
```

Then you'll have to do this:

```
>>> sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(r"C:\path\package"))
>>> import module
```

Hope this helps!